# Visual studio does not create output file without any error message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm a computer science, and I have a project that needs to create an output file using c++. The coding is correct but the visual studio doesn't create the output file for me. To make sure is not a typo error, I tested my code using the C++ online compiler and the code is working file with the file output. I did ask my professor to help me with this problem he tested my code at his end, the file output created in his repository but somehow my visual studio doesn't create the output file, and the code was running fine no error message so far. I try to run it as an admin, restart my laptop and uninstall then reinstall the visual studio but nothing work. any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

here is my code if anyone wonder

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.txt");// Open the file input
ofstream fout("output_1.txt");// create the file output.txtx
ofstream fout_Sor("output_sorted.txt");//create the file output_sorted

double calcDistance(double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2)
{
    // A function to calculate the distance and return it

    double mathX = pow(x1 - x2, 2);//calculate with the power to 2
    double mathY = pow(y1 - y2, 2);
    double mathZ = pow(z1 - z2, 2);

    double calDistance = sqrt(mathX + mathY + mathZ); // squart the distance

    return calDistance;
}

int main() {
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2;
    vector<double> distance;
    


    while (fin.good()) // REad the file which doesnt know how man yvalua
    {
        fin >> x1 >> y1 >> z1 >> x2 >> y2 >> z2; // Save it in side variable
        distance.push_back(calcDistance(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)); // call the fucntion to calculate and save it into vector


    }

    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i++)// Save each value of the vector to the output file
    {
        fout << distance.at(i) << endl;
    }
    
    sort(distance.begin(), distance.end()); // sort the vector

    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i++)
    {
        fout_Sor << distance.at(i) << endl;// Save the sort value into the output_sort file
    }

    // close file
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
    fout_Sor.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try searching the solution directory for the file.  IIRC, MSVS uses the folder where the source files are as the working directory for the program.

Comment: The default working directory in the debugger should be `$(ProjectDir)` which is a Visual Studio variable that points to the folder containing the project. This applies to all Visual Studio versions and not "Visual Studio Code" which is a completely different program with a similar name.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that those file objects are failing to open the file (i.e. file not found, wrong directory, etc...).  It's really not a great idea to declare instances of complicated objects (like files) as global variables.  Construc those objects in your `main` function and print an error if the file fails to open.

Comment: Unrelated: `while (fin.good())` is flawed. The logic looks something like 1. If stream is good, 2. read from stream, 3. use data read from stream 4. goto 1. if the stream is rendered invalid, it will be at point 2, after the check at point 1, allowing point 3 to proceed with invalid data. Prefer something more like `while (fin >> x1 >> y1 >> z1 >> x2 >> y2 >> z2) { distance.push_back(...); }` because it reverses the order of points 1 and 2. The body of the loop only enters if all of the variables were read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Like all other file opening functions, the `ifstream& ofstream` class uses the current directory when providing a relative path.

1. First of all, I suggest you use an absolute path `ofstream fout("D:\\testfolder\\output_1.txt");` to test whether the file is created.
2. Find the directory where your project is located to see if there are `.txt`s.
3. If you don't find them, I suggest you search the two `txt` files in the whole disk.

If it still doesn't work, I suggest you reset the VS settings `Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings`.

[image]